# C# return negative result into zero

Tags: c#

I want my  total result to return 0 if it's a negative total result.

I have tried the following

```
Double Apoints,Bpoints,Cpoints,Dpoints, Majortotalpoints,Totalmisses,Totalpoints.

Majortotalpoints=Apoints+Bpoints+Cpoints+Dpoints-Totalmisses;

Pointshandgun.text= Majortotalpoints.ToString();

Apoints =convert.int32(MajorApoints.text)\*5

Bpoints =convert.int32(MajorBpoints.text)\*4

Cpoints =convert.int32(MajorCpoints.text)\*4

Dpoints =convert.int32(MajorDpoints.text)\*2

Totalmisses =convert.int32(Totalmisshandgun.text)\*10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you put your total result into a variable called `totalResult`, you could check if that is greater than or equal to 0 (is positive) and if it is, return it, else return 0.

```
return totalResult >= 0 ? totalResult : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`return Math.Max(0, anyExpressionHere);`